# Not able to start spark session in Anaconda Jupyter - sparknlp.start() nlp FileNotFoundError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I imported lib, pyspark import is also fine, sparksession is also started but upon starting spark its giving error.

how to fix it ?
Using anaconda jupyter , and installed directly from anaconda pip install ,
please share any possible reason for issue

```
import sparknlp
from sparknlp.base import *
from sparknlp.annotator import *



spark = sparknlp.start()
```

Error ---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20004/1200795233.py in <module>
----> 1 spark = sparknlp.start()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sparknlp\__init__.py in start(gpu, spark23)
     63         builder.config("spark.jars.packages", maven_spark24)
     64 
---> 65     return builder.getOrCreate()
     66 
     67 

...
   1418             # Start the process
   1419             try:
-> 1420                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1421                                          # no special security
   1422                                          None, None,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your system does not have the path created for hadoop to use the windows dependencies i.e. winutils.exe.
Create a download hadoop repository from github, create a new environment variable named Hadoop_home (or what ever you want to call it). In the values mention the path to the downloaded folder which contains "bin" and save it.
Restart your system and then start anaconda jupiter notebook again and rerun. It should work fine.